# React и jQuery... what?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, trello

Вопрос касательно библиотеки React. Насколько я знаю, она почти всегда конфликтует с другими библиотеками, работающими с DOM. Пишем свои таски в сервисе Trello, скачал расширение для хрома Wappalyzer, которое показывает на чем работает сайт и какие плагины/api юзает. Так вот, оно показывает, что у трелло фронт на реакте, но еще есть jQuery и jQueryUI. Возможно я не прав в утверждении выше о конфликтах, если у вас есть больше опыта с этим, подскажите, реально ли вообще прикручивать jQuery к реакту? И нужно ли это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в принципе ничего не мешает внутри с react.render вызывать любую дичь. у меня сейчас текущий проект на реакт+d3 ну а что поделать

Comment: вообще то может и там есть jQuery который не используется.Приведу пример:Вы устанавливаете Laravel + React пишите готовый проект на нем и в конце открываете и видите что wappalyzer показывает React + jQuery + Lodash + Zepto а почему так.А дело в том что Laravel сам устанавливает эти пакеты .Я думаю также с другими проектами где есть jQuery + React.